# 更新時に再起動が必要なツールを再起動せずに更新させる手法の名称はありますか

Tags: linux, windows, sql, browser

さまざまなツールやOSで、更新するときに再起動が必要なことがあると思います
こうしたときに再起動をせずに更新するといったことをする場合について、何か名称はついていますか？

SQL Serverを更新するとき再起動を求められたが再起動をしたくない、という場合に素直に「SQL Server 更新 再起動せず」というふうに調べると「再起動をする必要があります」などの文章が検索結果にヒットし、自身が求めている情報が出てこないことが多いためこの質問に至りました。

Comment: これとかでしょうか。[Ubuntu 18.04 その309 - ソフトウェアの更新からライブパッチの設定が可能に](https://kledgeb.blogspot.com/2018/12/ubuntu-1804-309.html)

Comment: 再起動の対象が「OS」なのか「SQL Serverなどのプロセス単体」どちらを指しているのか明確にすると回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: Windows系だとこちらの方が馴染みでしょうか。質問内容と合っているかとは別に語感として。[ライブアップデート](https://support.norton.com/sp/ja/jp/home/current/solutions/v61260769), [Live Update 機能を利用できる状態にする方法について](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/ja/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/kA230000000ePpJ.html), [ライブアップデート](https://www.metatrader5.com/ja/terminal/help/start_advanced/autoupdate), [LIVE UPDATE 6マニュアル](https://jp.msi.com/page/Live-Update-6-Manual)

Answer (score 2):

コンピュータサイエンスでは [Dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating) [動的アップデート](http://kk-river108.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/12/22/020443) と言ってて手法とかが研究されていますが、製品でそう標榜しているのは無いみたいですね。
「再起動せず」も英語だと [rebootless update で見つかりました](https://ksplice.oracle.com/doc/ksplice.pdf)。
高可用性システムの文脈では全体的にはサービスを止めないアップグレードを [in-service upgrades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability_software#Features) と言うようです。
live もよく使われるほか、[hot patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(computing)#HOT-PATCHING), [zero downtime upgrades](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/managing-zero-downtime-upgrades-861253112.html) や（設定を適用するときとかに）on the fly というキーワードも使われるようです。